# Stata groupby average and first observation give wrong number

Tags: stata

I have a city-year level panel data that looks like:

```
city        year    mayor   growth     
Orange      2001    A       9.599998    
Orange      2002    A       14.9    
Orange      2003    A       14.6    
Orange      2004    A       13  
Orange      2005    B       9
Orange      2006    B       12.7
Orange      2007    C       18.4
Orange      2008    D       20.7
Orange      2009    D       16.5
```

I want to calculate for each mayor in each city:
(1) the growth in his first year as the mayor
(2) the rolling average growth since his first year

My code is:

```
bysort city mayor (year) : gen rollavg = sum(growth) / sum(growth < .) if mayor != "" & growth != .
bysort city mayor (year) : gen year1growth = growth[1]
```

It works for most of the data, but for some city/mayor Stata returns random numbers:

```
city        year    mayor   growth     year1growth  rollavg
Orange      2001    A       9.599998   10345.59     10345.59
Orange      2002    A       14.9       10345.59     5180.245
Orange      2003    A       14.6       10345.59     3458.363
Orange      2004    A       13         10345.59     . 
Orange      2005    B       9          9            9
Orange      2006    B       12.7       9            10.85
Orange      2007    C       18.4       18.4         18.4
Orange      2008    D       20.7       20.7         20.7
Orange      2009    D       16.5       20.7         18.6
Orange      2010    D       12.5       20.7         16.56667
```

For example, it works for mayor D: Year1Growth = 20.7 which is the growth rate in his first year 2008. Rolling average also works, 18.6 = (20.7+16.5)/2 and 16.56 = (20.7+16.5+12.5)/3.

However, the numbers are totally wrong for mayor A.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: See the `stata` tag wiki for advice on giving data examples. In particular, we need to know if for any of these variables we are seeing value labels.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this. I note that your example is inconsistent as your variable names for your data example and for your results are not identical.     (Corrected in an edit to the original question: my data example and results are consistent in names, but different.)

My only guesses are that

1. There is some confusion about what is in what variable in your real dataset.
2. Although you are showing us what look like numeric variables, some or all of those variables may have been produced by an `encode` of an original string variable that contained numbers. That is a known way to produce complete garbage. The advice is always to use `destring`, not `encode`.

The `if` qualifier is irrelevant to this example.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str6 City int Year str1 Mayor double Growth
"Orange" 2001 "A" 9.599998
"Orange" 2002 "A"     14.9
"Orange" 2003 "A"     14.6
"Orange" 2004 "A"       13
"Orange" 2005 "B"        9
"Orange" 2006 "B"     12.7
"Orange" 2007 "C"     18.4
"Orange" 2008 "D"     20.7
"Orange" 2009 "D"     16.5
end

bysort City Mayor (Year) : gen rollavg = sum(Growth) / sum(Growth < .) 
bysort City Mayor (Year) : gen year1growth = Growth[1]


list, sepby(Mayor)

     +--------------------------------------------------------+
     |   City   Year   Mayor     Growth    rollavg   year1g~h |
     |--------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | Orange   2001       A   9.599998   9.599998   9.599998 |
  2. | Orange   2002       A       14.9      12.25   9.599998 |
  3. | Orange   2003       A       14.6   13.03333   9.599998 |
  4. | Orange   2004       A         13     13.025   9.599998 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------|
  5. | Orange   2005       B          9          9          9 |
  6. | Orange   2006       B       12.7      10.85          9 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------|
  7. | Orange   2007       C       18.4       18.4       18.4 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------|
  8. | Orange   2008       D       20.7       20.7       20.7 |
  9. | Orange   2009       D       16.5       18.6       20.7 |
     +--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I just edited the variable names so they are consistent. In the real dataset, mayors are coded by IDs not names, since some people have same names. So we assigned each person a unique ID, which is numeric (int). To use groupby, shall I convert ID to string if this is the problem?

Comment: Whether the identifier is string is likely to be immaterial here. The error you report is that the numerical results are wrong. Otherwise the only shared currency here is data examples we can run.

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice! The error was fixed... It turns out that was the error in the raw data...